# Do the military really use GA planes as target practice?

Tags: safety, military

In the September issue of the [British Microlight Aircraft Association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Microlight_Aircraft_Association) (BMAA) magazine, someone wrote in to say that whilst flying their [C42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ikarus_C42), two [Typhoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurofighter_Typhoon) fighter jets passed them (one either side) a few times at high speed, at the same altitude, before flying away.

They said, when they contacted the nearest tower frequency, that they were told the military sometimes use [GA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_aviation) as target practice (*obviously* they're not actually doing any 'firing').

The writer did provide some [Flightradar24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flightradar24) screenshots to prove the incident had happened, but I wonder if ATC really told them that.

Do the military use GA for target practice?

This was all in UK uncontrolled airspace by the way.

Comment: Strange "target practice". Intercepting an aircraft (e.g. lack of radio contacts) or shooting an enemy plane are done in different ways (never on both side).

Comment: If there is a link to the actual article in the magazine, this might be better suited to [skeptics.se] (skeptics requires a notable source, hence the need for an actual article rather than just "I saw....")

Comment: What is BMAA magazine?

Comment: I won't answer, as I have nothing authoritative, but many years ago I back seated on an RAF Nimrod sortie over the North Sea and they absolutely used civilian vessels as targets. Not for weapons, but as contacts to close in on, to ID using Sonar etc. It wouldn't surprise me to hear that Fast Jets do similar, though again, I doubt this is 'target practice' in any form, but rather RADAR intercepts, tracking etc though there is an obvious level of increased danger vs maritime patrol and boats

Comment: @tedder42 British Microlight Aircraft Association. I can't link the article as it is not digital, and I don't want to post a picture of the print without their permission

Comment: @Cloud I think what you are asking for are "intercepts" instead of "target pratice". An intercept is to guide your aircraft such that it meets up with another aircraft. Target practice is to shoot at something for practice. I very much hope that the jets in question did not shoot down GA aircraft :D. 
Because of this difference, you also get answer for aerial gunnery practice instead of intercepts...

Comment: Is it not clear that however much they might choose to deny the very idea, still
any air force which didn't use GA planes for target practice would be shirking its responsibilities?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, that's a pretty broad and unsubstantiated accusation.  Air Forces have plenty of training aids at their disposal that don't require the passive and unknowing cooperation of civilian aircraft.  That's not the same as saying they may illuminate and even lock onto GA aircraft occasionally for practice, but to imply that *not* doing so is "shirking its responsibilities" is pretty extreme.

Comment: @MichaelHall That's not at all 'broad' and it doesn't need substantiation, except to people with no real interest in military operations and training. 

You and anyone else who doubts that is welcome to explain at least why you think your country's military should be denied the most realistic training they could get.

Will you try that or explain why not, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, I have 20 years in military aviation in the USMC and USN. I wasn't an F16 driver, but I can confidently say that running radar intercepts on passive Cessna 172s is not "*the most realistic training they could get*", and not doing so does not impair our warfighting capabilities in the least. We honed our skills fighting very capable military trained aggressors, and I trust that the USAF still does the same thing today.  Will you please explain how you have arrived at your opinions on effective military air combat training?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, you are coming across as unhinged.  "Denying a wider accusation"? 
 What does that even mean?!

Comment: Cessna 172s are a ubiquitous GA aircraft, I just chose something at random.  Would it make a difference to my point if I had not specified actual type aircraft?  And my experience started 40 years ago, and "understanding" some time prior.  But to your point, *so what*?!

Comment: "*who cares whether radar intercepts on any passive craft is '… most realistic training*"  Well, it seemed like you did in the first comment that triggered this...

Comment: @MichaelHall Who doubts that denying something irrelevant about, eg, Cessna 172s is a standard tactic for avoiding a wider accusation by trying to force the focus onto a more-specific case? In like mode, who cares whether radar intercepts on any passive craft are '… most realistic…'?

Who doubts failing to use every method available amounts to negligence, despite your personal views? 

My experience of military aviation started not 20 but 50 years ago and so what? For reasons outside your ken, my *understanding* of military aviation started not 50 but more than 60 years ago and so what?

Comment: Please, Michael, either back off or go to Chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149072/discussion-between-michael-hall-and-robbie-goodwin).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As for the US, they do practice intercepts on GA planes and they aren't supposed to. A F-16 was involved in a hull-loss crash due to perceived loss of control during a low-speed interception, and the [mishap investigation report](https://www.afjag.af.mil/Portals/77/AIB-Reports/2022/23%20March%202022%20ACC%20F-16%20Mishap%20Beauregard%20Parish%20LA,%20AIB%20Report%20for%20Public%20Release.pdf) states:

> **The MFL [Mishap Flight Lead] and MP [Mishap Pilot] Failed to identify/correct risky or unsafe practices by intercepting a non-participating GA aircraft**
>
> Through the course of interviews with the mishap unit, there was a lack of consensus regarding whether the intercept of a non-participating, uncoordinated GA aircraft operating outside a MOA is a permissible training event. However, a thorough understanding of the existing training rules makes it clear that any simulated target of interest (TOI) must be non-maneuvering, or only maneuver with full coordination between the TOI, the controlling agency, and the ACA interceptors.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that "they aren't supposed to" perform practice intercepts on GA planes?

Comment: @MichaelHall Did you bother to read the bottom 75% of the answer?

Comment: I did.  It doesn't say what you are claiming.  In fact, "*there was a lack of consensus regarding whether the intercept of a non-participating, uncoordinated GA aircraft operating outside a MOA is a permissible training event.*" says almost the opposite.

Comment: @MichaelHall Read the very next sentence.

Comment: I have. That pertains to maneuvering. Without a more complete discussion on training rules, one could say that intercepts on non-participating aircraft are permitted as long as they are not maneuvering. From that quote alone you cannot say "they aren't supposed to". That's the statement I am asking you to justify.

Comment: Neither does the part in bold you referenced validate your claim that "they aren't supposed to". Failing to properly identify a risk is not the same thing as violating a policy or regulation.

Comment: @MichaelHall "failing to correct unsafe practices" implies violation pretty clearly to me, as does the quoted note on what the training rules make clear. Pointing out that the unit lacked consensus on that is obviously pointing out a failing, not suggesting the opposite. And non-participating aircraft can't possibly be "non-maneuvering or only maneuver with full coordination"... it could maneuver at any time. As the report points out. Read it if you doubt what user71659 is saying, but the answer is pretty clear to me as is.

Comment: @mbrig, I get your point, but poorly and unsafely executing some action that is otherwise permissible is not necessarily a violation of that which you are permitted to do safely. In crude terms, "*failing to correct unsafe practices*" simply means that the pilot f@#$ed it up. (I spent my career reading safety investigation reports, this is standard verbiage for pilot error...) Good point too on the lack of consensus. Which highlights that if the active duty members of the squadron were unsure it is doubtful that any of us internet randos will know the answer for certain.

Comment: Regarding "maneuvering" this term has a specific meaning in the context of ACM, or Air Combat Maneuvering. Yes, a non-cooperating civilian target could turn at any time, but that isn't what the training rules are referencing. (I inserted the term maneuver "defensively" in another comment string to emphasize this, and was lambasted...)

Answer (score 12):

I can’t speak for what Great Britain or some other government does, or what you mean by ‘target practice’.  In the United States, for aerial gunnery practice, we employ a number of unmanned air vehicles as targets, most notably, the QF-16, which is a retired F-16 fighter converted for this purpose.  I have never heard of light general aviation aircraft being used as targets for aerial gunnery exercises.

General aviation aircraft are sometimes used to simulate threats where the military assets interact with them, but do not fire upon them.  One example are joint exercises with the civil air patrol.  CAP will use Cessna 172 and 182 aircraft to intentionally violate practice TFR areas, allowing for military fighters to fly simulated intercepts.  And it comes in handy, as NORAD reports hundreds of TFR violations every year; mostly people with drones, but there are occasions where some ding dong doesn’t read the NOTAMs and flies his Piper Cherokee into a presidential TFR or similar event.  They are generally  intercepted and handed over to law-enforcement on the ground.

It is possible as well, that military aircraft may track civilian aircraft using fire control radars in exercises for practice, similar to what was described above.  I do know the military has also used civilian ground structures as practice ‘targets’ in simulated air strikes. I remember reading stories from Colonel Tony Tolin, who used to command the 37th TFW (F-117As) out of Tonopah, NV.  He said that, during the 1980s, their aircraft would fly specific missions at night, targeting specific buildings or structures discussed in preflight briefs as a simulated strike mission in preparation for war.  I remember one case where Mr. Tolin stated that  their target is a specific cabin with a dock on the north shore of Lake Tahoe.  The only thing missing was that the jets never dropped the bombs (nor did they carry any on these flights), and for additional safety, never lased civilian buildings as well.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149058/discussion-on-answer-by-carlo-felicione-do-the-military-really-use-ga-planes-as); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 9):

In the airspace I used to work, we had several Military Operations Areas (MOAs) that extended from 500 feet above ground level up to, but not including, FL180. When the military used the airspace, all IFR aircraft were routed out of/around the airspace to allow them to practice air combat maneuvering.

Nothing precluded VFR traffic from flying through an active MOA. Sometimes you would see the fighters line up on an untracked VFR target and fly pretty darn close to the VFR aircraft. We're they "targeting" the VFR? I don't know for sure, but it sure seemed like it on radar.

Comment: Fascinating. Did you ever discipline them for this?

Comment: Honestly, other than violating separation (for GAs) I really dont see much of an issue with interrogating, targeting, even locking a GA aircraft to practice use of the targeting systems. Its literally just different patterns of radar sweeps. Flying too close to a non-participant? Yeah, not cool from a safety standpoint. But acquiring, and locking from 10km away? Please, do explain to me the terrible harm being done other than keeping our fighter crews trained on how to use the hundreds of millions of dollars systems their service branch strapped to their butts....

Comment: @TankR. - would you be cool with someone pointing a loaded gun into your face to do some scope checks, and they pinky promise they wont shoot by accident? The militaries around the world have killed enough civilians through sheer stupidity that I would never be comfortable with nonsense like that.

Comment: @TankR. To simply avoid the negligible chance of firing on a civillian target by mistake, they are never used for target practise. Period.

Comment: @Davor, military aircraft do not normally carry live ammo into MOAs.  They very rarely carry any live ammo anywhere in CONUS.  If they do, it would be in a tightly controlled live fires exercise in a restricted area.  Not a MOA with civilian traffic around.  Even during coordinated large scale exercises in a MOA, (such as Red Flag) coordinators will call "knock it off" if there is an interloper.  The loaded gun example you suggested simply doesn't happen.

Comment: @MichaelHall - the loaded gun is proximity itself. And also it's hilarious how many times non-live ammo turns out to be quite lively.

Comment: @Davor, I don't think it's hilarious at all, and would challenge you to find a single instance in the last 75 years of a US military aircraft accidently shooting down a civilian airplane during a training exercise.  (Alec Baldwin's recent mishap and others like it are irrelevant in this context if that is what you are hinting at...)  P.S.  What do you mean by "proximity itself"?

Comment: @Davor, I am very familiar with that incident.  The causal factors are completely irrelevant to this discussion.

Comment: @Davor In the friendliest way I can put this... I am convinced yall need to take a deeper look into the process required to actually launch a piece of locked on ordinance from a combat aircraft. Its not as simple as 'wait for tone, OOPS! My finger slipped...' I am not aware at the moment, though I'm sure a quick google will net an answer, but its possible the radar system of the aircraft (not on the missiles, if equiped) could be used to find, track, and lock without activating any potentially loaded, and armed, ordinance. Its literally just different types of radar sweeping patterns.

Comment: @Jpe61 see above. Normal radar is a regular interval sweep (regular repeating spike of RF energy). The track phase is a more active sweep that keeps the returned signal mostly in the aperture of the scan area while, scanning around the returned signal to better work out the signals bearing, distance, speed, etc (a very fast series of possibly irregular RF spikes as the area around the craft is scanned). In the lock phase the singal is centered wavering slightly around to detect any deviation in its flight path (constant RF singal). The () bits are how tracking and lock of enemies is detected.

Comment: @TankR.  Military planes do track civillian trafic with their radars, that's for sure. What counts as "targerting" here may be up for discussion. I understood the question such that "target practice" means actually targetting as in acquiring as a target for weapons.

Comment: They're the same systems, other than the missiles that have radar systems onboard. Even then the aircraft radar feeds the ordinance internal radar data so it knows where to point its radar, then informs the pilot it has the target. But to loose a missile still isnt a 'oops, my finger slipped' kind of affair. Heck, if thats the worry, there are platforms that can detect, track, and target by multiple systems (land, sea, and air), patched through an EWACS to a command center, which could then order a missile fire, and guided to the target using this massively interconnected data network...future